# Trouble uploading image via paperclip and aws-sdk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am using paperclip to upload photos to an AWS-S3 bucket.  The photos are being accessed through a separate feed using Mechanize.  I recently updated my gem file, and now paperclip apparently requires the aws-sdk gem instead of the aws-s3 gem.  Now I am debugging code to accommodate the aws-sdk gem and I am stuck at uploading a file.  My working code below using the aws-s3 gem:

```
image = agent.get(url).body
filename = "#{listing_id}:#{i}.jpg"
AWS::S3::S3Object.store(filename, image, S3_BUCKET_NAME)
"https://s3.amazonaws.com/#{S3_BUCKET_NAME}/#{filename}"
```

I get this error: `undefined method`store' for AWS::S3::S3Object:Class`

and from what I can gather, the new code is going to look something like this:

```
key = File.basename(filename)
s3.buckets[S3_BUCKET_NAME].objects[key].write(:file => filename)
```

Using aws-s3, the image was referenced in the store method. How do I reference the image using aws-sdk?

for now I am going back to an old paperclip version and reinstalling aws-s3, but I would like to keep my code up to date if possible.  Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: Same problem here. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I never did find an answer to this.